# zlib fails to decompress gzip data

Tags: node.js, gzip, zlib

I'm using the `zlib` node module to compress data, encrypt it with the `crypto` module and then safe it to a file. Reading and writing the file works fine, as well as encrypting and decrypting the data, but how ever when I try to decompress the data with `zlib.unzip` it returns the following error.

```
Error: incorrect header check at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:153:17) errno: -3, code:'Z_DATA_ERROR'
```

I've already checked, whether the data read from the file is the same as written to it, which is the case. Using `zlib.gunzip` instead to bypass the automated header detection of zlib doesn't change anything.

```
function encrypt(data, enc) {
  zlib.gzip(data, (err, compressed) => {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(enc.algorithm, enc.key, enc.iv);
    compressed = cipher.update(compressed.toString(), 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
    fs.writeFile('passwords', compressed, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });
}


function decrypt(enc) {
  fs.readFile('passwords', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(enc.algorithm, enc.key, enc.iv);
    data = decipher.update(data.toString(), 'base64', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
    zlib.unzip(data, (err, uncompressed) => { // THIS LINE SEEMS TO THROW THE ERROR
      if (err) console.warn(err);
      console.log(uncompressed);
    });
  });
}
```

**Update:**
I've been trying to investigate this problem further, because it's still appearing and i would really like to include compression as a feature.

However what i found out so far, is that apparently the error only occurs, when using `zlib` and `crypto` in combination, both work fine on their own.

Apparently `zlib` got a problem with `crypto` tinkering with the compressed data, because switching the order of them seems to solve the issue somehow. But compressing more or less random data, `crypto` returns after encryption, doesn't makes much sense.

Maybe somebody got an idea on that?

**Update 2:**
I again looked further into this and it appears, the decrypted data doesn't fit the encrypted data. However it is being decrypted properly and `crypto` doesn't throw any errors. That's probably why `zlib` isn't abled to unzip the data.

Comment: Use `base64` encoding instead of the default `utf8` for decoding a `Buffer` to string. Put a test check for `compressed.equals(Buffer.from(compressed.toString('utf8'), 'utf8'))` and you'll notice that it may not always be equal...

Comment: That does not solve it for me. It results in an decryption error `Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`.

Comment: If the result of [`(de)cipher.update()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_decipher_update_data_inputencoding_outputencoding) is `Buffer`, use [`Buffer.concat`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) to concatenate the final block instead of using `+` operator

Comment: I'm not sure, whether that's what you've meant, but I guess I fixed it now. You mentioned Buffer.concat, which actually gave me the idea to discard the conversion from buffer to string completely, because both `crypto` and `zlib` support buffers and `fs.readFile` returns a buffer in the first place. Now it appears to be working. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Yes, the conversion from buffer to string is really unnecessary in this case. I'm glad it helps you..